# Win32 API vs Java socket flushing (TCP)

Tags: java, sockets, winapi, tcp, flush

In Java, one can write a couple of bytes (or however many bytes that is less than the buffer's size) to the socket's output stream and then flush it, in case some bytes need to be sent immediately. In Win32 API, there doesn't seem to be any sort of flush function, so I feel like "flushing" in this case is just padding the rest of the buffer with dummy bytes (probably zeroes) to force the send function to, well, send the data. My question is, how does Java (or even C#, perhaps) implement such a thing under the hood? That is, if I had a Java socket communicating with a Win32 socket somewhere, how would they communicate given that there will be some flushing needed? For example, if the Java socket's buffer were to be flushed (calling `flush` on the socket's `OutputStream`), what would I get on the Win32 side (by calling `recv`)? And the reverse? Would I see some padding behaviour? Would the Win32 side need to know the Java side's buffer size? Something unrelated?

Comment: Have you tried looking into sources? .Net core is fully available on github and you can see how exactly it is implemented

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First recall that TCP provides a bidirectional stream of bytes. On one side you write bytes to a socket and the other side can read them from the socket. There is no guarantee whether writing 4 bytes will result in one read call that fetches 4 bytes on the other end. It could also be 2 times 2 bytes. It's no packets or buffers, and therefore "padding the rest of the buffer with dummy bytes" seems like a bad idea, since the other side will eventually receive those dummy bytes (and interpret them for whatever).

Next on to the question:
On the base of all the application there are the OS socket APIs, which provide the write/send calls for the socket. When you write to the OS socket the bytes that are writing are basically only written into the socket send buffer of the OS, from which they will be sent to the remote side at some point of time. This point of time depends on how filled the state of the send buffer is and how things look on the network (TCP windows, network congestion, etc.). However you normally don't have to care about it, the OS will simply send the data eventually and there is no need to flush something. There is one setting on the OS which can be used to influence the sending behavior, which is the nagle algorithm (or TCP_NODELAY) setting. If nagle algorithm is disabled (NODELAY = true) this means the OS will try to send the data immediatly after the write call and doesn't wait for more data from the application in order to send less IP packets. You **can** use this to reduce latency in case of small packets, but there is no need for it, since the OS will send the data anyway. So it's not a flush in the sense of a required flush.

For the Java side I'm not exactly sure what the flush is doing. It could be that the Java OutputStream has an internal buffer which is only written to the OS socket with the write system call once either a certain treshold of bytes in the buffer is reached or flush is called. Or flush exists purely in order to satisy the OutputStream base class and does nothing extra. You should be safe by using flush on the Java side (or on other platforms where it exists) and doing nothing special in native socket APIs.

Answer (score 2):

Flushing a Java socket output stream does nothing. Flushing a `BufferedOutputStream` does something, but only to the application-side buffer. In neither case is there a system call involved other than the `send()` or `write()` implied by the flush. You're looking for something that doesn't exist.

> so I feel like "flushing" in this case is just padding the rest of the buffer with dummy bytes (probably zeroes) ...

No.